# How to retrieve the index of an XML element with a specific attribute in AS3?

Tags: xml, indexing, actionscript

Does anyone know if there is a way to retrieve the index of an XML child element with a specific a attribute in ActionScript?

Say...

```
foo.child.@attribute //index of
```

I tried using the method like this:

```
foo.child.@attribute.childIndex()
```

but it returns `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [hasOwnProperty](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html#hasOwnProperty%28%29) method works for me:

```
foo.child.(hasOwnProperty("@attribute")).childIndex()
```

But if element with `@attribute` is not unique, then the right code is:

```
foo.child.(hasOwnProperty("@attribute"))[0].childIndex()
```